# Android - how am I supposed to fix the error based on this exception trace?

Tags: android, exception, trace

There is an error in my Android application that happens quite often, based on the crash report on the Developer Console.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1304)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Unfortunately, I can't replicate that error on my Android phone.

I dont' know where to start: in the trace there isn't any reference to my code.

Can somebody give me some suggestions on how to identify the root of the problem, please?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious things I can think of:

1. `AbsListView.obtainView()` I believe is communicating with the Adopter to populate the list view.  Make sure there is never a case where you could return a null back to the list view.
2. There may be a bug in some version of the platform.  Unfortunately the developer console does not currently show you the platform version the error reports came from.  Hopefully this will be added in the future to help diagnose such a situation.
3. It is possible someone is running a non-standard or custom build of the platform that has bugs. You might be able to determine this by looking at the "platforms" section for the different devices the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a virtual device and load it in the emulator, start with the smallest resolution.

I am suspecting that it has to do with screen size and somehow you are trying to draw in a pixel that doesn't exist.